# How can I filter out sites which had been automatically translated?

Tags: browser, blocking, translation

often I stumble upon websites which had been automatically translated by some associated or built-in application and badly so. I assume those websites get my language from the browser identification and set it as target language for their built-in translation algorithm.

Is it at all possible to identify such websites and filter them out automatically? Upon reading, I quickly spot such sites, but I would like to spare myself the wasting of time with them

Comment: I believe this post is off topic here (learning/software recommendation).   There is no trivial way to do this - maybe yoi could write a filter that trys the page with 2 different language hints or try to tie it in with  an AI engine and build a dataset - but both these things are significant undertakings and imperfect.

Comment: I often face the same issue. What I've e experienced, they've .ru domain, so it's easy to spot and don't open them. If that's not the case for you, please post same examples you want to avoid